# how should i wire up this 2-way z-wave switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, dimmer-switch, neutral

I want to replace the 2-way switch on the left with a z-wave dimmer switch.

Currently this box has a 2-way Dimmer on the left, and a 3-way switch on the right.  As noted, all of the neutrals(marked W and are White) are currently wired together in a single bundle.

When I replace the 2-way dimmer, which uses a neutral, what is the correct way to wire up the neutrals?

Thanks for any help!

[image: Wiring in my kitchen box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the neutral from the Z-Wave switch into the bundle of white wires, that's your neutral for that box.

(P.S. the red and black wires from the 3-way switch are not "always hot" and "switched hot", they're both travelers.)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I installed my z-wave switch into the 2-way, and it seems to be working correctly, but there is a very soft buzzing noise coming from the switch when switched on.  If i install back into the wall I don't think I would hear it.  Is that OK?  That's new to me.

Makes sense the 3-way would both be travelers. I had the other side of that 3-way turned off, and my voltmeter still said there was power to one of them either way, so I feel like one is the traveler, and the companion must be the other side (Sorry for my labeling).

Comment: WOW you respond fast. Upvote on the way and answer acceptance (i'm new here, thanks for your patience).    Is the soft buzzing noise coming from the switch OK though?  Or is that likely something else I did wrong?

Comment: @PowerLevelZero -- the soft buzzing could very well be the switch, and as long as it's not getting too hot to hold (carefully, so you don't get bit by 120V!) in your hand, it should be fine.